# when creating new module throw Experimental support for decorators error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

i am trying to generate new module in angular project with

`ng g module core/employee-applicant --routing=true`

and the new module generated throw an exception

> **Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to
> change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in
> your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.**

and in other module it dosn'et generate that error.

**the new module with the error**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { EmployeeApplicantRoutingModule } from './employee-applicant-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EmployeeApplicantRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class --> EmployeeApplicantModule (the error on visual studio code red under line){ }
```

**the old module which dose not pop up that error**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/shared/modules/material.module';
import { PipesModule } from 'src/app/pipes-module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    PipesModule,
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

and the same thing with the routing module generated with that new module.

and for `experimentalDecorators` i added it in every tsconfig file in my project

**tsconfig.app.json**

**tsconfig.spec.json**

**tsconfig.json**

**tsconfig.base.json**

and if anyone can tell me what is the difference between these files

and another thing when i try to import it to **app.module** it dosen't show up i think it's because of that error

Answer (score 1):

guys it seems like a bug in visual studio code

i hard imported it in other module by writing the whole path then the error disappear

at least this solve it for me i don't know how ...

Answer (score -1):

I have the below in my tsconfig.json, and it works fine

```
   {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
     "experimentalDecorators": true
      }
    }
```